# Mapping Dataflows iterate (avoiding Foreach loop)

Tags: azure-data-factory

Within Mapping data flow (trying to avoid Foreach)

Is this possible with a structure like this container/directory/File

```
Land/’Folder1/20210815’/a.csv
Land/’Folder1/20210816’/b.csv
Land/’Folder2/20210815’/c.csv
```

I want to load Folder1 and subfiles and sink them to Base container in the data lake

```
Base/’Folder1/20210815’/a.csv
Base/’Folder1/20210816’/b.csv
```

In dataflow, I will add one derived column which is loaddate (or anything I want in dataflow).

All files contain the same csv columns structure column1,column2,column3,loaddate

I do not want to specify a date basically bulk load any csv under a subfolder

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my example using a Copy Activity without using a For Each:

**I have 4 files with this structure in Blob storage:**

```
Folder1/20210815/Placeholder.csv
Folder1/20210815/Placeholder5.csv
Folder1/20210816/Placeholder3.csv
Folder2/20210816/Placeholder3.csv
```

[image: Copy Data without for each]

**Here is the copy data details:**

[image: 3 Files Written]

**Here are those files and as you can see the subfolders were copied over. This theoretically should work in Data Lake, but I can't be sure. It definitely works in Azure Blob Storage.**

[image: Subfolders copied to Output Folder]

**Here are the contents of the 20210815 Subfolder:**

[image: Subfolder Contents]

Comment: FYI, I did attempt a dataflow and could get the data over, but it would not copy the subfolders as well.